# Hide menu bar Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to hide the menu bar of Powershell ISE?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: @manojlds why not? think for example in all modern web browsers or even the same windows explorer. They hide the menu simple because it takes space that could be used for other things and all the functionalities that provides could be invoked with hotkeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can import modules into the ISE, there is no way to alter the UI.