# Menu Bar not showing in Windows Powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell

I just installed the Windows Powershell in my windows 10 computer but the menu bar is not showing. I want to open new tabs and in the documentation it says one should click file, but my powershell has no Menu bar.
I searched a lot of stuff about how to make it show but nothing is working. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/335286/hide-menu-bar-powershell-ise) somebody asked if the Menu bar can be hidden, but according to the answer it can't. Does that mean I can't get it showing as well?

Comment: What happens if you press ALT? Normally on any application where the menu bar can be made hidden, it will temporarily show the menu bar. Now, I don't see any option to make it visible permanently, but at least that should help you. Also CTRL-T will create a new tab.

Comment: @LPChip Both of those don't work.

Comment: and you are sure you have opened PowerShell ISE? The normal powershell doesn't have a menu bar, but no editor either.

Comment: @LPChip Oh ok. Maybe I opened the normal powershell. How do I find that out?

Comment: @LPChip Ok i got it now. I opened the normal powershell. And just now I opened the ISE, which has a menu. Thanks a lot that  really helped.

Comment: What exactly did you install because PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 5.1 ISE are built-into Windows 10 and they cannot be uninstalled or reinstalled.

Comment: @Ramhound I have to admit that I am a bit confused myself. The installation file says PowerShell 7.2.5. But I typed a command in the shell to return the version and it says 5.1. So I am not sure.

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 exists on Windows 10+ whereas PowerShell 7.2.5 is installed separately.  The two executables and environments are separate.  So which ISE are you using? You can't get them confused because they are properly labled.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to differentiate and clarify whether you're dealing with the ISE, PowerShell, or Windows PowerShell?

Comment: @music2myear ok did it just now.

Comment: So you weren't actually working in the ISE? If that is the case you'll want to edit the title too, which states you WERE working in the ISE.

Comment: @music2myear uh, the whole problem here is that he thought he was using ISE while in fact he wasn't and the answer was a clarification that there's a difference. How on earth can you edit a question to provide an answer and being expected to be taken seriously here?

Comment: I can see that side of things, but the best and most accurate information in the question leads to a) clear and good answers, and b) future visitors accurately recognizing their own problem in an existing question and finding a solution. In my opinion, this question is better served with an accurate title, and the body of the question recording those incorrect expectations that lead to the error. I'm not asking OP to answer in his question, just to accurately represent the situation there.

Comment: ok everybody. I just updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments exchange, it appeared that even though you did install Powershell 7.2.5 you opened Powershell 5.1, which is already installed on Windows 10.

Neither are the ISE however. Powershell ISE is a different interface with editor and menubar, whereas Powershell itself is only a command prompt like window.

When you search for Powershell in the startmenu you can see that the ISE version mentions ISE:

[image]